# Property of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I need the formal proof of this fact. I define the permutation matrix in this way

given $\pi$ a permutation of $n$ elements its permutation matrix is: $${P}_\pi=\begin{bmatrix} {e}_{\pi_{1}} \\ \vdots 
 \\{e}_{\pi_{n}} \end{bmatrix},$$ where ${e}_i$ is the row vector with $1$ in the $i$-th position and $0$ in every other position. How can I prove that $${P}_{\sigma}^T{P}_{\pi}^T={{P}_{\sigma\circ\pi}}^T\quad?$$

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, for every $j=1,\ldots,n$,
$$
P_\pi e_j=e_{\pi^{-1}(j)}.
$$
Hence
$$
P_\pi P_{\sigma}e_j=P_\pi e_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}=e_{\pi^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(j))}=e_{(\sigma\circ\pi)^{-1}(j)}=P_{\sigma\circ \pi}e_j.
$$
Thus
$$
P_\pi P_{\sigma}=P_{\sigma\circ \pi}\quad\text{or}\quad
P_\sigma^TP_{\pi}^T=P_{\sigma\circ \pi}^T.
$$